# Linking error duplicate symbol _kCHPointerSize with CHDataStructure static lib

Tags: ios, xcode, chdatastructures

I am trying to use the [CHDataStructures](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/CHDataStructures) static library for iPhone in my Xcode project. I included it with `# import "CHDataStructures.h"` in my class header. However, when I compile my project I get the error:

> d: duplicate symbol _kCHPointerSize in /Users/sam/Desktop/Apps/libCHDataStructures.a(Util.o) and /Users/sam/Desktop/Apps/build/Apps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Apps.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppsAppDelegate.o
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

I am using GCC-4.2 compiler and I have tried LLVM GCC 4.2 as well. I also tried with `-ObjC`, `-all_build`, and `-force_build` flags set in the build setting but it is not compiling. I also tried to clean Target, and also make sure with static lib included with target binary or not. But I couldn't figure out the problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where does `kCHPointerSize` exist and how is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

Probably far too late now but I just ran into something similar so if it is still an issue, check your import statements.

It looks like you might be referencing `kCHPointerSize` in both the `AppDelegate` and your `Util` class.

In my case I had imported the same `.h` file once too often. I removed one of the import statements and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Open Util.h file,
replace the line

```
HIDDEN size_t kCHPointerSize;
```

with

```
OBJC_EXPORT size_t kCHPointerSize;
```